# Calculate sum every 3rd element - array java

Tags: java, arrays

I had an initial String array(FileContent) which I've converted into ArrayList (MatchingContent).

String FileContent = "2017-04-03, 11:25, 2; 2017-04-02, 11:30, 8; 2017-04-03, 14:42, 9";

Now, I need to iterate through every 3rd element and calculate the sum of them but below section is not working:

```
    Integer[] intarray=new Integer[MatchingContent.length];

    for (int i=0; i<MatchingContent.length; i+=3)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        intarray [i] = Integer.parseInt(MatchingContent[i]);

        sum = sum + intarray[i];

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks but this declaration also not working:

Integer[] intarray=new Integer[MatchingContent.length];

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Don't add this information in the comments.  Edit your question and provide the new information there.

Comment: In what way not working? Please quote any error message precisely. In case of an exception being thrown, post the stacktrace in the question, nicely formatted as code, and tell us the line in your code where the stacktrace says the exception occurred. We can help you *much* better then.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring (and initialising) the `sum` inside the loop which means it would intialise in every iteration, overwriting (or throwing away) the previous value. What we need to do is to change the declaration and do it outside the loop, that way, the previous value will be preserved.

Also, you don't need `Integer[] intarray` as we are storing the result in `sum` and hence, don't need to store individual elements separately. Below are the examples:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<MatchingContent.length; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(MatchingContent[i]);
    }
}
```

Or

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<MatchingContent.length; i+=3){
    sum += Integer.parseInt(MatchingContent[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this declaration also not working: Integer[] intarray=new Integer[MatchingContent.length];

Comment: @Savantes you don't need that declaration anymore. If you see my answer, I have removed that bit as it was redundant anyway

Comment: @DarshanMehta, don’t you agree that the asker would be helped much better if you explained what was wrong in his or her code, than from spoonfeeding code that works?

Comment: @OleV.V. Added the explanation